# Perl array(@data) to variables($data)

Tags: perl

I am doing socket programming.
The data ($ data) received from the socket contains 4 bytes of length data + json data.
I want to trim the length and only parse the json.

I have completed the code and it works fine. But I wonder if there is a more efficient way (algorithm).

Is there an efficient way to move arrays to variables in perl?

```
@tmpp = split(//,$data); #data = socket data

my $t1 = sprintf("%02x%02x%02x%02x",ord($tmpp[0]),ord($tmpp[1]),ord($tmpp[2]),ord($tmpp[3])); 
$t1 = hex($t1); #t1 = length 

my $json;
my @tmp = @tmpp[0..-1];
foreach(@tmp){ $json .= $_;}<br>
print $json;

Ok Print ;
```

Comment: Are you following standard networking conventions, i.e. the sender converts the 32-bit from local endianess to network endianess before writing it to the socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard case for [pack/unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). The `N/a` template will unpack a string of length `N` (in network byte order):

```
my( $json ) = unpack 'N/a', $data;
print $json;
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.
pack / unpack is the best choice.
But it takes $ data as an argument. Is there a way to pack / unpack @data (array)?

Comment: @SAnjiHolic You already have `$data` as a string and keeping it that way is the most efficient approach. If you have an array, `@tmpp`, then `unpack 'L>/a', join '', @tmpp` could work and would be relatively fast. Splitting a string into an array and then working on the array is usually a bad approach in Perl.

Comment: @SanjiHolic If the answer works for you, please accept it ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers )

Comment: @StefanBecker Thanks, `N` is a much better/clearer template

Answer (score 0):

If you have what you say you have, you could simply peel off the length prefix.

```
my $json = substr($data, 4);
```

But this would mean that the length prefix is useless, which suggests you have a major bug earlier in your program. Did you properly read from the socket?

```
sub read_bytes {
   my ($fh, $bytes_to_read) = @_;
   my $buf = '';
   while ($bytes_to_read) {
      my $bytes_read = read($fh, $buf, $bytes_to_read, length($buf))
      die($!) if !defined($bytes_read);
      die("Premature EOF") if !$bytes_read;
      $bytes_to_read -= $bytes_read;
   }

   return $buf;
}

sub read_uint32be { unpack('N', read_bytes($_[0], 4)) }

sub read_string {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   my $len = read_uint32be($fh);
   return read_bytes($fh, $len);
}

my $json = read_string($sock);
```